# join 2 table and the value in a specific manner

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I have 2 table one is master and another one is the child, now I want to write a query in such a way that all the value from the master should display and the count of that particular parent id row from the child if present otherwise it should display 0.

this my master table

[image]

and this my child table

[image]

and I have tried this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) 
from Activity LEFT JOIN Notifications on Notifications.ActId = Activity.ActId 
GROUP BY name
```

and the output i got is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `COUNT()` so it only counts the child records (and not always the master).

```
SELECT Activity.name, COUNT(Notifications.ActId) 
from Activity 
LEFT JOIN Notifications on Notifications.ActId = Activity.ActId 
GROUP BY Activity.name
```

`COUNT()` won't count `NULL` values (from your `LEFT JOIN`), so you will only count records from the `Notifications` table this way.

Comment: SELECT a.name,a.ColorCode, COUNT(n.ActId) AS activity_count from Activity a LEFT JOIN Notifications n on n.ActId = a.ActId WHERE n.StDt <= CURDATE() AND n.LastDt >= CURDATE() AND a.Stat =0 AND n.Stat =0  or n.NotId IS null GROUP BY a.name, when i select the a.ColorCode it is giving me sql error and i want that column too

Comment: @sayyedtabrez add the `a.ColorCode` to the `Group By` columns also. Try to read about grouping and aggregate functions, you will use them a lot!

Comment: yes, got it thanks once again, @EzLo  SELECT a.ActId,a.name, a.ColorCode, COUNT(n.ActId) AS activity_count from Activity a LEFT JOIN Notifications n on n.ActId = a.ActId WHERE n.StDt <= CURDATE() AND n.LastDt >= CURDATE() AND a.Stat =0 AND n.Stat =0  or n.NotId IS null GROUP BY a.name,a.ColorCode,a.ActId